# Как проверить все ли символы в строке пренадлежат верхнему или нижнему регистру в си?

Tags: c

Как проверить все ли символы в строке пренадлежат верхнему или нижнему регистру в си?

Comment: iswupper()/iswlower()

Comment: Что насчёт допустимых значений и кодировки? Одно дело однобайтовый ASCII, совсем другое какой-нибудь UTF.

Answer (score -1):

Кодовая страница ASCII разработана таким образом, что буквы одного регистра сгруппированы в некоторые блоки. Так букам латинского алфавита в верхнем регистре соответствуют коды от 65 (буква А) до 90 (буква Z). А буквам латинского алфавита в нижнем регистре соответствуют коды от 97 (буква а) до 122 (буква z). Поэтому, всё, что нужно это проверять отсутствие принадлежности кода символа (типа char) диапазону от 97 до 122. Если хоть одно значение входит в этот диапазон, то с уверенностью можно сказать, что хотябы один символ представлен в нижнем регистре. Соответствующую функцию написать не сложно.

Comment: Не работает для не-ASCII символов.